# How much lower than the ideal torqe curve is the actual torque of a PMSM running at overspeed?

Tags: torque, speed, vfd, pmsm

VFD-controlled PMSM's are said to produce constant maximum torque up to the rated speed. Above the rated speed the VFD performs defluxing and produces constant power. This should then mean that at 200% of rated speed, the produced torque should be 50% of rated torque, but in reality it is claimed to be closer to 25% of rated torque.

Why is the actual torque so much lower than the ideal torque? What actual relationship between speed and torque should be expected?

Comment: I think different motor designs require different amounts of defluxing current. Maybe those which require the highest defluxing current are not able to maintain constant power above base speed without overheating. I think your question could be improved if you linked to the spec sheet for an actual motor.

Comment: @mkeith I wish I had a spec sheet with this information! In any case, I was hoping for general knowledge of PMSM characteristics.